# spark dataframe caching is extremely slow

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my code I have a dataframe that I want to cache (df.cache()). It is extremely slow. I looked at the metrics and the GC times are ~0.2 to 0.3 seconds. Tasks: Succeeded/Total says (0/400) and the memory as well as compute consumption is quite low. Can someone point out a few parameters I can tune to remove this bottleneck.

Comment: Hi, may I ask the size of your Dataframe (GB/rows)? Is the 400 partitions without repartitioning? Also how many executors do you have and I assume the file/table is on HDFS so what is the replication factor? Spark needs to shuffle data around in order to make it available all the executors. So a metric over your cluster's network/IO would help to identify the bottleneck.